# Missing .frm and .idb files, cant remove table

Tags: mysql, database, innodb

I have a weird scenario where a technician deleted the .frm and .idb files for a table from one of my servers, fortunately it was a non critical table. I'm trying to recreate the table however when trying to use the CREATE TABLE, DROP TABLE or ALTER TABLE I get errors cos the tablespace still exists. I'm not really able to move the good tables to a new schema, drop the old schema then recreate the table that way as there are critical tables still in the schema which cannot be taken offline. Any thoughts on how I get rid of this "broken" table?

Answer (score 2):

I created a test table:

```
mysql> use test;

mysql> create table test ( id serial primary key );

mysql> insert into test () values ();
```

Check that the files exist in my datadir:

```
$ cd /usr/local/var/mysql/test
$ ls
db.opt   test.frm test.ibd
```

Do the unthinkable!

```
$ rm test.*
```

Now I have a catch-22 situation:

```
mysql> show tables;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> create table test (id serial primary key);
ERROR 1050 (42S01): Table 'test' already exists

mysql> drop table test;
ERROR 1051 (42S02): Unknown table 'test.test'
```

What to do?

```
mysql> create schema recovery;

mysql> create table recovery.test ( id serial primary key );

mysql> system cp /usr/local/var/mysql/recovery/test.frm /usr/local/var/mysql/test/
```

The `.frm` file stores table metadata in MySQL 5.x. Now that I have a `.frm` file, MySQL lets me query the table.

```
mysql> select * from test;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
+----+
```

That's funny — how does it know about that row of data? Didn't I `rm` the `.ibd` file?

Answer: Files are not truly deleted while a process still has a filehandle open to it. Since I have not restarted the MySQL Server process, the `.ibd` tablespace file still exists, even though I unlinked it from the datadir!

Anyway, I can now drop the table. This removes the `.frm` and `.ibd` *AND* closes the filehandles to them, so they are truly deleted from the filesystem.

```
mysql> drop table test;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

And finally I can now create a new table of the same name, even with different columns.

```
mysql> create table test ( bar int primary key );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
```

Comment: Note that this only works if MySQL has not been restarted.  And it depends on the way *nix handles files, so it probably will not work on Windows.

Comment: You mean the part about being able to query the table only works if MySQL has not been restarted. At least the part about being able to jury-rig it so you can at least drop the table should work regardless.

Comment: It depends on the details inside MySQL.  The delete function in unix is "unlink", which, as its name sort of implies, the reference to the file is removed from the directory.  However, until the code actually _closes_ the file, the file exists (and occupies space on disk.  But there is no way to see it.  If there happened to be a hard link (`ln`, but not `ln -s`), "unlink" would remove one alias for the file, but not the other(s).

Comment: This kludgy way of unlink+close is a feature when you want a temp table that automatically goes away when your program goes away.  And hides the file from everyone.  The sequence open(), unlink(), write... read..., then finally close() the file.  Open adds a directory entry; unlink, not close, removes it from the directory.

Comment: My point about Windows is that this concept was so alien to Windows that it was not many years ago that they added something like it, first as "Junctions", then something closer to unix.

Comment: I try not to think about Windows anymore. Gave it up around 2007, and my life has been better since then.